# UITextField -resignFirstResponder fail

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, ios5, exc-bad-access, resignfirstresponder

I recently updated XCode (4.2 with iOS5 SDK) and now my app is throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS everytime i use "resignFirstResponder".

I'm familiar with memory management and check out that nothing was released before... The crazy part is that "becomeFisrtResponder" would work.

Working fine:

```
if(_TextField==input){
    [inputPassWord becomeFirstResponder];
}
else
{
    [input becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Failing:

```
if(_TextField==input){
        [inputPassWord becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else
    {
      [_TextField resignFirstResponder];
    }
```

Any idea of what it could be?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that input isn't the first responder at the time?

Comment: don't think so.

`if(_TextField==input){
[inputPassWord becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else
    {
        if([_TextField isFirstResponder])
        {
            NSLog(@"YES");
            [_TextField resignFirstResponder];
        }
        //[inputPassWord resignFirstResponder];
    }`
is logging "YES" then failing

Comment: maybe the becomeFirstResponder caused it to be retained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is going to be of any help but is the logic in the second example right?

The first one looks like you're checking to see which TextField has done something and then setting firstResponder on the other.

The second one seems to do nothing since it's only calling `[input resignFirstResponder]` if Input is NOT the textField being tested.

Have you tried switching the two lines of code in the second example, or using `!=` instead of `==`.  Might be worth a try.

I don't think that should cause your problem though but I'm pretty new to this'

Comment: have you tried sticking NSLog() in directly after the resignFirstResponder line just to see if that is the fail?

Comment: alternatively if this is some kind of iteration through a bunch of subviews are you sure that _TextField is actually a textField? I mean does it fail if you run it with "input" instead of _TextField?

Comment: hum interesting... Logging "OUT" right after the if/else block works... i guess something goes wrong as it leaves the `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)_TextField`

Comment: Got it!

Turns out i was returning "YES" from:

`- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)_TextField`

since i was not using the regular behavior it was not appropriated.

Returning "NO" works like a charme!

Thanks every one!